# Using ZClip with Live in Jquery (for modal window)

Tags: jquery, zclip

I am using the flowplayer overlay tool to load a div in a modal window. Any suggestions on getting zClip (or something comprable) to work? This is the closest I have gotten:

```
 var cc = jQuery.noConflict();
 cc('#WOTW').ready(function() {
    cc('#codeButton').live('click', function() {
        cc('#codeButton').zclip({
            path: '/site/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: cc('#copyCode').text(),
            afterCopy: function() {
                cc(this).next('.check').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This works but ONLY on the second click... Which I find very odd. help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of the 'open' and 'close' parameters in Jquery UI dialogs to simulate the modal behavior. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/samdel/mmkMZ/14/

Answer (score 0):

calling zclip does not actually initiate the copy what it does is create a an embedded flash object which is overlayed on top of #codeButton. When that is clicked it preforms the copy.

So in your code the first click created the overlay and the second click was on the overlay and performed the copy.

It should work if you just use

```
var cc = jQuery.noConflict();
cc('#WOTW').ready(function() {
    cc('#codeButton').zclip({
        path: '/site/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: cc('#copyCode').text(),
        afterCopy: function() {
            cc(this).next('.check').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```